# Limit based on bounds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $k\in(0,1)$ be fixed. If $\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(kx)\leq \epsilon$ and $\liminf_{x\to\infty}f(\frac{x}{k})\geq -\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then is it possible to say $$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x)=0.$$

Comment: Is $\varepsilon$ fixed or does the hypothesis hold for all $\varepsilon>0$?

Comment: for all $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Same remark as [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054746/). OP: If you were asked this as homework, I am curious to see what will happen when you hand in the answer below.

Comment: this is not my homework, i just asked for only curiosity.